# Нужно создать метку для Telegram Open Network (TON)

Tags: предложение, метки, создание-метки

Уважаемое сообщество сайта stackoverflow, не могли ли бы Вы создать метку для Telegram Open Network (TON)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Создать метку может любой участник с [достаточной репутацией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags). Если у вас есть 300+ репутации то этого достаточно создать новый вопрос и написать метку: при нажатии на кнопку сохранить она будет автоматически создана.

Также автоматически метка может быть удалена, если не останется вопросов с этой меткой (допустим, метка будет снята с вопросов или удалена, ЕМНИП, это происходит после трёх месяцев неиспользования).

Если технология новая — может стоит просто подождать, пока будет задан первый вопрос. Если она действительно такая популярная, как вы говорите — то это случится очень скоро. Вопросов по различным коинам не так уже и много в основной массе, толи нишевая вещь, интересная только узкому кругу лиц (может быть и вы тоже просто являетесь крупным экспертов, но в узкой теме?), толи уже наелись хайпа, толи ещё не пришло время.

Текущий вопрос о том, как создавать кошельки и переводить граммы не относится к [вопросам программирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), поэтому я боюсь, что если вы будете его публиковать — то рискуете схватить несколько минусов, а потом и вопрос будет сначала закрыт, а потом удалён (вопросы с минусами автоматически удаляются спустя некоторое время).

Если вы готовы написать какой-то готовый вопрос по тематике сайта — могу помочь с созданием метки.

Comment: Вроде ж 3 месяца - это висящая на единственном вопросе метка, а для безвопросных сутки?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49553173#49553173